# Android, keep buttons from ignoring parent padding?

Tags: android, xml

I have a scroll view inside which is a linear layout and inside the linear layout there are some buttons. I defined some padding for linear layout, but when scrolling, buttons ignore that and overlap the scroll view. What to do?
here is the xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/item"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fadingEdge="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/item"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:text="Button" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#1e90ff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:text="Button" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#1e90ff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:text="Button" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#1e90ff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so because padded space is a part of scroll view. Linear layout is inside scroll view and padding space is inside linear layout, and whatever is inside scroll view will get scrolled. So, padded space also gets scrolled.

If you want to keep the padded space, add padding space to scroll view.

Code :

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:fadingEdge="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button03"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:text="Button" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#1e90ff"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:text="Button" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#1e90ff"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:text="Button" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#1e90ff"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Now, padded space won't get overridden by buttons.
Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: So useful. Using the point that everything inside the scroll view gets scrolled, i managed to set the scroll view inside a linear layout and set the padding to scroll view itself instead of its child views. Then i made the linear layout's corners rounded and now everything sounds good. Thanks Abhinav Puri.